# Instantiate private inner class with static method

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Is there a better way of doing something like this (or does it even make sense):

```
class A {
    public static B buildClass() {
        return new B();
    }

    private class B {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

I'm building a simple factory class. It seems weird to me that I can instantiate a non-static member inside a static method, but it seems to work.

Any advice as to how I can improve this?

Comment: "It seems weird to me that I can instantiate a non-static member inside a static method" --- you are just calling a `new` operator. How is it different from, say `+` operator when is used in a static method?

Comment: because the thing im calling `new` on is a non-static member of the same class. that is why it seems odd to me; im used to only being able to access things inside static members that are also static. but, this is probably due to my ignorance of nested classes.

Comment: "im used to only being able to access things inside static members that are also static" --- you're not accessing anything here, you're using a `new` operator. Would `1 + 2` expression confuse you? How is it different from `new B()` expression?

Comment: Class B is private inside class A, how do you manage to return a private class through a public method ?

Comment: @Steve: that was my first thought as well, but "but it seems to work" confused me :-S

Comment: This code doesn't compile at all. _Inconsistent accessibility: return type XXXXXX.A.B' is less accessible than method 'XXXXXX.A.buildClass()'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static method cannot use the INSTANCE fields or methods of the class in which is defined.
Your call doesn't use any instance field of method of class A. It creates a new instance of class B and tries to return it. And here you have a problem that cause the failure of the compilation.
Class B is private to A and cannot be returned by a public method of A because the external world (outside A) doesn't know anything about B. Make it public

For example:

```
class A 
{
    public int publicField = 0;

    public static B buildClass() 
    {
        // Fails, it is an instance field, cannot be used by a static method
        // without creating an instance of class A
        publicField++; 

        // Works, create an instance of A and use its public fields
        A myself = new A();
        myself.publicField++;

        // works because B is public
        return new B();
    }

    public class B 
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, youre right. i just now saw in the code i was working with that an interface was public, but the class that implemented the interface was private. anyway, this is exactly the type of explanation i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but usually the class is not private, but rather the constructor.

```
public class MakeHello
{
    public static MakeHello CreateHello()
    {

        return new MakeHello();
    }


    private MakeHello()
    {

    }
}
```

and elsewhere

```
        var a = MakeHello.CreateHello();

    // Can't instantiate because private
        var b = new MakeHello();
```